# Swift: Loop through an Array and present information on screen item by item (with screen updating)

Tags: arrays, swift, uikit, label, screen

I am storing information in an **array** and want to present it on an **UIButton/UILabel** on the screen one by one with a wait time of one second.

Of course the system is smart and calculates the full functions out before updating the screen to save resources... how can I prevent this and have the screen updated after running each item?  (I am using UIKit and not SpriteKit).

```
 @objc private func infoButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

      for item in Array {
          statusButton.isHidden = true
         updateScreen()
          presentArray(item: item)
         sleep(1)
      }
}

  func presentArray(item: ArrayItem) {

      statusButton.isHidden = false
      statusButton.titleLabel?.text = item.status

  }
```

I tried

```
    view.setNeedsLayout()
```

and setting specific parts into

```
      DispatchQueue.main.async { xxx }
```

but non of those tricks seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution could be to use [scheduledTimer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1412416-scheduledtimer) to update your button or label like this:

```
let sampleArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
var numberOfItem = 10
var sampleTimer:Timer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sampleTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(presentArray), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func presentArray(){

    if numberOfItem >= 0 {
        sampleButton.setTitle(String(sampleArray[numberOfItem]), for: .normal)
        numberOfItem -= 1
    }
    else {
        sampleTimer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: **Timer.scheduledTimer** requires an (at)objc function, but I cannot hand over an item  if I declare **presentArray** as (at)objc. 
I will still try it maybe with a global counter. Thank you, I will update this if it works.

Comment: :( does not seem to work. I included everything except the Timer in the presentArray, but the screen is only updated after the timer runs through (- index out of range)... any other ideas?

Comment: Did you add scheduledTimer in the for loop? let me be more thorough. what scheduledTimer does is to run the selector function in every timeInterval. so what you need to do is to define how many times you want to do the selector function (by using a variable like length of your Array maybe) not adding the timer in the for loop. I will update my answer to be more precise.

Comment: Thank you! This works very well.  Exactly what I have been looking for! 
And performance is way better than the solution I figured out below. :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting the content of **infoButtonTabbed** in:

```
 DispatchQueue.global(priority: DispatchQueue.GlobalQueuePriority.default).async { xxx }
```

and the content of **presentArray** in

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async { xxx }
```

it now cycles through the array presenting one item after another.